# i need help making my ruby while loop more accurate and easier to read

Tags: ruby, game

```
  while enemy.health > 0 && player.health > 0
    enemy.health = enemy.health - player.damage
    player.health = player.health - enemy.damage
    puts "#{enemy.name}'s health = #{enemy.health} your health = #{player.health}"
    sleep(0.5)
  end
```

This is my ruby while loop for my game i am making and i need help making it easier to read and more accurateany suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "more accurate"? Does this code calculate a wrong result?

Comment: As per the [ask] guidelines, please edit the question, particularly the title, to state the purpose of the code rather than your main concern about the code.

Comment: A bit more context and code wouldn't hurt too, it's easier to reason with the big picture in mind rather than only focussing on a tiny, very specific, part of the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the shorthand operator -= so you don't have to type the same thing twice.

`enemy.health -= player.damage`

`player.health -= enemy.damage`